# How to convert a jpg image to base64 with freemarker

Tags: image, web-services, binary, base64, freemarker

I am looking for a way to send a link to an image such as

[image: imageLink]

and converting the base64 binary to a string. It doesn't matter if it's via a function in freemarker or via a Webservice. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the solution, just written a php-script:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $link   = $_GET['link'];

    $imagedata = file_get_contents($link);

    // alternatively specify an URL, if PHP settings allow
    $base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);

    print($base64);
?>
```